# Jqgrid - Clear File upload from form

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using Jqgrid and Ajaxfileupload to upload a file. It works fine but when I'm going to upload another file in the form appears the file that I have upload. I would like to clear the file fields

This is my code

```
afterSubmit : function(response, postdata){
                    var respuesta = response.responseText;                              
                    var param  = $("#resTables").jqGrid('getCell',lastSel,'idProyecto');
                    $.ajaxFileUpload({
                        url: "doajaxfileupload.php?imagen=&tabla=proyectos&categoria="+  param,
                        secureuri:false,
                        fileElementId:'fileToUpload',

                        dataType: 'json'
                   });
```